# Accessing locked files on external HD

Tags: windows-8

On Windows 8 Pro failure I took the HD out and plugged it in as an external drive on another laptop to get some files I NEED.  However, I can't access folders such as the the AppData under Users.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kate

Comment: Just take ownership of these files and folders - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx

Comment: @NikolaD, would you mind posting that link as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking ownership will  do this,

I would prefer **third party tool for taking ownership of files in Windows 8** , its so easy , you can do this in 3,4 clicks, **TakeOwnershipEx** is an awesome software for  this , [check this link for the download link](http://www.programmerfish.com/takerestore-ownership-of-files-and-folders-using-takeownershipex/#.UlO8P9LryCA) and screen shots tutorial for using it,

**For doing it manually**

Right-click the file or folder you want  to take ownership of, go to Properties, and then click the Security tab.

click advanced tab and then click owner

you can select owner from the list, For users no present in the list,

click Other users and groups and, in Enter the object name to select (examples), type the name of the user or group, and then click OK.

For details On how to change ownership in Windows 8 manually , [check this link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html) it explains with Screen Shots